# Verification Failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting') in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am developing webapp in flutter and there is login with phone number using firebase auth.i am getting error on event of getotp ( Verification Failed: [firebase_auth/unknown] An unknown error occurred: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')

i have already try flutter doctor ,pub get ,pub upgrade

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Am using firebase_auth: ^4.7.3.

Add this to index.html

Flutter shows some warning though.

```
<head>
<script>window.flutterfire_web_sdk_version = '9.22.1';</script>
</head>
```